# Screen freezing for large task execution

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, closures, background-process

I am trying to use completion block but still screen is freezing may I know what is wrong here? Or how can I improve?

```
func generateRandom(text: String, frame: CGRect,
                    stackFont: [StackTextFont], completion:  @escaping (StackableTextStyle) -> Void) {
    
    var style = generateStyle(text: text, frame: frame, stackFont: stackFont)
    var maxCounter = 0
    while style == nil || !isValidStyleForFrameSize(style!.0, frame: frame, stackFonts: style!.1.fonts) {
        style = generateStyle(text: text, frame: frame, stackFont: stackFont)
        maxCounter = maxCounter + 1
        if maxCounter > loopBreakerAt {
            break
        }
        print(maxCounter)
    }
    completion(style ?? (text, StackTextGroup(fonts: stackFont)))
}
```

Note: Assume that loop might execute more than 100000 time to get the validate style

Calling the function

```
var i = 10
var counter = 1
let group = DispatchGroup()
    while i > 0 {
        group.enter()
        QuoteNeuralParser.shared.generateRandom(text: text, frame: frame, stackFont: stackFont) { (style) in
            /// Avoid duplicate styles
            if !self.data.contains(where: {$0.1.1.fonts == style.1.fonts}) {
                if let img = self.getIMStackLayer(frame: frame, style: style).toUIImage() {
                    self.data.append((img, style))
                    i = i - 1
                }
            }
            
            /// Loop breaker for infinite attempt
            counter += 1
            if counter > 30 { i = -1 }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: you using while loop in main thread, you need to do the loop in background thread

Comment: try read this https://www.viget.com/articles/concurrency-multithreading-in-ios/

Comment: You've tagged this with multithreading, but I don't see any evidence that you're executing this on a separate thread. If you execute a loop 100000 times on the main thread, yes it will block the main thread. You might want to add your code for how this method is called, and how the caller deals with the completion.

Comment: @Corbell, I have added the caller code